# How would you fix an 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' error?

Tags: node.js, npm, chalk

I am trying to use the chalk npm.
My code is:

```
     const chalk = require('chalk');

          console.log(
          chalk.green('All sytems go') +
          chalk.orange('until').underline +
          chalk.black(chalk.bgRed('an error occurred'))
           );
```

And I receive this error in my terminal when I type node main.js

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/ezell/Documents/CodeX/NPM/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /Users/ezell/Documents/CodeX/NPM/main.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/ezell/Documents/CodeX/NPM/main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ezell/Documents/CodeX/NPM/main.js:1:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to switch to using the `import` keyword, as Chalk 5 only supports ESM modules.

---

So, to fix your code to adapt these changes, you need to...

1. Edit your `package.json` file to allow ESM imports. Add the following in your `package.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. Load Chalk with the `import` keyword, as so:

   ```js
   import chalk from "chalk";
   ```

---

If you, however, want to use `require()`, you need to downgrade to Chalk 4. Follow these steps to downgrade.

1. Replace your existing `chalk` key with the following in your `package.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "dependencies": {
       "chalk": "4.1.2"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then, run the following command to install Chalk from your `package.json` file. Make sure to run this in the directory in which your `package.json` file is in!

   ```
   $ npm install
   ```
3. Use the `require()` statement like normal.

   ```js
   const chalk = require("chalk");
   ```

---

In summary, these are the two things you can do.

- Stay with Chalk 5, and update `import` statements.
- Downgrade to Chalk 4, and keep `require()` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the import chalk from "chalk"; and "type": "module" worked!!

Comment: "add the following" OK, where at the end of the file?

Comment: @serge It doesn't matter where.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' error for nanoid:^4.0.0 & there are multiple ways to resolve this error:-

1)Use fix esm https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-esm module & import the module like this:

```
const someModule = require("fix-esm").require("some-module");
```

2)Use dynamic import as shown below:

```
import('nanoid') 
.then((res)=>{ console.log(res) })         
.catch((err)=>{ console.log(err) });
```

Just make sure you dont have type:"module" field in package.json in above both cases otherwise you got "TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension" error

3)Downgrade the module version to a stable old version, for eg in my case it was resolved when I downgraded nanoid version to :

```
"nanoid": "^3.1.22"
```

Comment: fix-esm is the way to go. Should happen by default.

Comment: fix-esm is a lifesaver.. wish I could have learned about earlier.. much headache would have been prevented

ESM can kiss my ass

Comment: fix-esm fixed the issue for not just this package but all of them. This package is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) is only compatible with ESM modules and thus wants you to load it with `import`, not `require()`.

From the doc:

> IMPORTANT: Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or
> a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now. [Read more](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v5.0.0).

So, your choices are:

1. Switch your project to an ESM module and load the latest version of Chalk with `import` instead of `require()`.
2. Install version 4 of Chalk which can be used with `require()`.
3. With a fairly recent version of Node.JS, you can use dynamic import to load the ESM module into your CommonJS module: `const chalk = await import('chalk');`

Answer (score 3):

Solution, this happens because you have to use the current stable release 2.x
first:

```
npm uninstall -D node-fetch
```

After that:

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```

This should work.

Comment: I really wished there was more explanation to this "solution".