# Firebase Functions Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, google-cloud-functions, eslint

It was working before but after updating it gives this error I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/video-intelligence": "^4.1.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "agora-access-token": "^2.0.4",
    "camelcase-keys": "^8.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.0.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.7.0",
    "googleapis": "^109.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.42.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.42.1",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**I used to write like this:**

```
import camelcaseKeys from "camelcase-keys";
```

**Now it started giving this error**

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of 
ES Module C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxx\functions\node_modules\camelcase-keys\index.js from C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxx\functions\lib\app-store.purchase-handler.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxx\functions\lib\app-store.purchase-handler.js to a dynamic i
mport() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Comment: can you check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820079/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804844/how-would-you-fix-an-err-require-esm-error)

Comment: tried. DOesn't work.

Comment: did you resolve this and how?