# Getting error while importing "query-string"

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, morgan

I started by creating an express generator app and try to import the query-string module but received this error.

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/USER/Desktop/Desktop/ELearning/Testing/node_modules/query-string/index.js from /home/USER/Desktop/Desktop/ELearning/Testing/app.js not supported.`
What am I missing every thing is working fine if I don't import the query-string module.Why only importing query-string module is giving the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804844/how-would-you-fix-an-err-require-esm-error